# Erlang: how to sign a 'CertificationSigningRequest', with a CA cert and private key

Tags: erlang, x509, csr

I need to sign on the server a CSR coming from a trusted client, with a certificate I have along with its private key.

In command line, I'd do something like

```
openssl x509 -req -in ClientCSR.csr -CA MyCert.crt -CAkey MyPrivateKey.key -out ClientCert.crt -days 365 -sha256 -set_serial 5
```

I'm struggling to do this from erlang.

Parsed by `public_key:pem_entry_decode`, the CSR gives me a `'CertificationRequest'` record, which I don't really know how to use further.

Reading the `public_key.erl` documentation, I think I should be using `public_key:pkix_sign` but that takes an 'OTPTBSCertificate' record as an input (and a private key, that I do have).

Is there anything I can do to take my `'CertificationRequest'` and turn it into an `'OTPTBSCertificate'`?
Or is that not the way to go?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, if someone reads this question, I ended up fincing this gist https://gist.github.com/emtenet/b48f948102d9a4904a78 that does pretty much what I was trying to do

Basically I manually extract pieces I need (subject and private key), create a `TBSCertificate`, sign it, and create an x509 certificate from this